# Failed asserting that two strings are equal in laravel testing while perfroming test Login redirect to dashboard successfully

Tags: php, laravel, testing, redirect

I am new to TDD and i am performing a unit test on a new project which is to perform a test  Login redirect to Dashboard. It redirects the user to dashboard when dummy user is created.
I applied it on all the other projects and this redirection test always passed successfully but here in this project it is not allowing me to redirect to the '/dashboard' but instead it says that the expected outcome is redirection to '/login'.

```
public function test_login_redirect_to_dashboard_successfully()
{
    $user = User::factory()->create([
        'email' => 'Admin@gmail.com',
        'password' => '12345'
    ]);
    
    $response = $this->post('/login', [
        'email' => 'Admin@gmail.com',
        'password' => '12345'
    ]);
```

And here i am receiving the following error
• Tests\Unit\AdminTest > login redirect to dashboard successfully
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.

```
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'http://localhost/dashboard'
+'http://localhost/login'
```

I don't know why i am not allowed to redirect to dashboard in this case because in front end it is working fine but in test cases it is not allowing me to redirect to '/dashboard' in any case.

Also when i only try to access dashboard and want to check whether the views exist or not then i receive the following error.

```
• Tests\Unit\AdminTest > dashboard view can be rendered
Failed asserting that '<!DOCTYPE html>\n
<html>\n
   <head>\n
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />\n
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='http://localhost/login'" />\n
  \n
      <title>Redirecting to http://localhost/login</title>\n
  </head>\n
  <body>\n
      Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost/login">http://localhost/login</a>.\n
   </body>\n
 </html>' contains "Dashboard Analytics".
```

Here it again asks me to redirect to the login page, but why? I am unable to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `redirect()` in your controller. If there's no problem in your `redirect()`. Try using `$this->assertAuthenticated()` in your test to check if your authentication is successful.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't helped me out.

Comment: @AzzamUmer user is authenticated or not after the request? If not of course you will never see the dashboard page thats the point.

Comment: I am authenticating the user by using actingAs($user) and before that i have created a model using factory so it should be authenticated.
I am using the same procedure in all the other models and it is working fine but only facing problem here.